# Is 'headers' parameter valid for redirects in python requests library?

Tags: python, http, python-requests

If I issue a GET request, such as:

```py
r = requests.get('http://google.com', headers = {"referer":"www.abc.com"})
```

The initial request will be redirected from http to https. My question is, if the "referer":"www.abc.com" header will also be attached to the redirected GET request to https://google.com?

Comment: why don't you try and see? :)

Comment: The only way I can think is to setup a web server and implement http-https redirection, which is what I have spent a few hour trying. In the meantime I want to see if anyone knows the answer that can save me a few hours. Is there any way that I can know for sure if the extra header arrives to the host that I don't own, say, google?

Comment: I have found out, and it dose!